# Godot saving variable path from one .gd to another .gd

Tags: dictionary, variables, path, save, global

I have in a global gdscript, and inside i have

```
var number1 = 0
var number2 = 0,
```

which normally could be accessed by any gdscript by global.number1 and global.number2.

Then i have a different script with a Dictionary inside that holds some values.
How can i make it work like this(see following):

```
var dict = {0: {path = "global.number1"}, {1: {path = "global.number2"}}
```

and then, instead of using several if-statements if i want to expand the number of objects in the dictionary, i can do this:

```
dict[n].path += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know what are you actually asking, but maybe you forgot to set the path to global in the second script?

Anyway you should clarify what's the question.